# Equivalent of SQL loader in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-loader

I have found SQL loader in Oracle is very helpful, fast and efficient. What is the MySQL equivalent of SQL loader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `MySQL Front 3.2`

and

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

(see docs)

Comment: Louis: it seems just like external table, Yeah I have tried but any suggestion please for sqlloader ?

Comment: @Suleman : Also called heidiSQL : http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql-front.shtml It is a solid tool to interact with the db. Also does import/export of text files, CSV files, ....

Answer (score 2):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)....

Provides much of the same functionality as you would implement in your control file except for byte ranges and 'WHERE' filters.